# Access a page only if valid login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

When the user enters the correct username and password, he/she will be presented with the `MyNewPage.aspx` page. This part works properly.  But, when I type `http://localhost:49296/Pages/MyNewPage` directly in the browser window without logging in I still am able to access this page. What I want to do is to restrict users accessing this page without signing in.

How can I do this?

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                        && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("MyNewPage", "Pages");

                    }
                }                
            }    
            return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put

```
[Authorize]
```

on the controller/action

Comment: You mean underneath `[HttpPost]` ?

Comment: Not on the logon action, but rather the actions that you want to restrict access to

Answer (score 1):

**Making sure a user is logged in to gain access to a view**
The easiest way to accomplish this is to use the Authorize attribute above a controller's action method. For instance, we only want to allow users to change thier password if they are already logged into the site. In order to prevent non-authorized users from reaching the change password view we can restrict access like this:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult ChangePassword()
{
    ViewData["PasswordLength"] = MembershipService.MinPasswordLength;
    return View();
}
```

You can also accomplish this manually by checking against the User object like this:
public ActionResult ChangePassword()

```
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account");

    ViewData["PasswordLength"] = MembershipService.MinPasswordLength;
    return View();
}
```

**Making sure a user is in a particular role to gain access to a view**
You may have some views which should only be accessable to users of a particular role. This can also be accomplished using the Authorize attribute like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

You can accomplish this in code as well using the following method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (!User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
        return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account");

    return View();
}
```

**reference: [Using our Role and Membership Providers](http://www.brianlegg.com/post/2011/05/09/Implementing-your-own-RoleProvider-and-MembershipProvider-in-MVC-3.aspx)**